# assign None to option when element is empty

Tags: scala

I have a list of Integer which I need to convert to Option, however when List is empty i need to assign it as none.
please suggest

```
val list: List[Int] = List()

val x = option(list)
```

if list is empty x should be none and if list has some value say List(1,2) then x should be Some(List(1,2))

please suggest

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Comment: I have been trying x = Option(y) which returns some(List()). I have tried switch case which were giving compilation error. Could you please suggest

Answer (score 1):

```
Option(list).filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

Comment: wow, Nice thank for your help

Comment: And could you please suggest how to get the same result if instead of list it is Double.. like Option(0.0).filter will throw error

Comment: `Option(double).filter(_ != 0.0)`